# Local variable in each class - python timed loop

Tags: python

I have a python file in a continuous loop reading from an external file, I have a lot of different data points I'm reading and have a class (fb) that I'm calling to feed the locations of each point (m1.x, m2.x etc....) The file loops every 30 seconds.

I need a variable in the loop which is not reset for each instance I'm using. If I define it within the loop it's reset and if I use a global variable I can't use it for multiple variables.

So in the example below 'test' counts by one for all instance as its a global variable and self.X is reset after each loop. Neither of which do what I need. I was attempting to use threading but this causes even more problems with the modules I'm using. So if anyone has any ideas on how to create a local variable which is not reset within a class which is looping that would be great. Thanks.

```
test = 0  
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def loop1(sc): 
    class fb:
        def link(self):
            global test
            test = test + 1
            print test

            self.X = self.X + 1
            print self.X

    m1 = fb()

    m1.X = 1
    m1.link()

    m2 =fb()
    m2.X = 0
    m2.link()

    # Update loop every 10 second    
    sc.enter(10, 10, loop1, (sc,))


# end loop
s.enter(1, 1, loop1, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: I've read this several times and still cannot understand what do you want.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anyone use `sched` without `time.sleep` except in toy examples. You really want to block your whole program for 10 seconds at a time?

Comment: If ``class fb`` was in global scope you could utilise a ``class attribute`` to hold onto that value, yet that doesn't seem right either. I confused that in your loop you ``m1.X = 1`` which resets it any way. Are you looking for a counter of number of times ``loop1`` is called?

Comment: @sotapme: Both `m1` and `m2` are brand new objects created on each function call anyway, so there's no "it" to reset…

Comment: Then is it that you need a class attribute if you don't want an instance attribute. What do you want this variable to do?

Comment: @sotapme: A class variable wouldn't help, because the class is _also_ created anew on each function call.

Comment: @john: I'm really not sure I've understood what you want to do. I'm pretty sure that various things are _not_ what you want to do, but there are countless possibilities that might be. Can you please either clarify your question, or at least read the two answers you've gotten and comment on them?

Comment: Well perhaps fb shouldn't be created a fresh every time unless you've a reason for doing so. Could you make fb a sublclass of a Borg class?   Couldn't you just pass this unspecified variable in with the call to ``loop1`` via ``sc.enter(10, 10, loop1, (sc,mysecret))``. Also notice that  @wRAR has got 3 upvotes on his initial comment that should tell you something like you need to be clear in what you problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an object **y** that counts the turns of the loop, not the number of instances created in each turn (= self.X), nor the cumulative number of instances created since the start of the program (= test)

I've got the following program to obtain the object **y** that increments by one only at each turn of the loop. It needs to creates an entirely new class at the beginning of a turn.  The instruction

```
fb = type('fb',(object,),{'__init__':initer,
                              'link':linker,
                              'CLASSIES':0})
```

does this creation of a completely new class. It is evidenced by the display of the classes created: `print 'id(fb) == %d' % id(fb)`
The identity of an object is the place where it lies in the memory. If it is not the same id, it is not the same object:

```
import sched,time

test = 0  
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

Y = 2000

def initer(self):
    global test,Y
    if self.__class__.CLASSIES == 0:
        Y += 1
        self.__class__.CLASSIES += 1

def linker(self):
    global test,Y
    test = test + 1
    self.X = self.X + 1
    print 'Y == %d' % Y
    print 'test == %d     self.X == %d' % (test,self.X)


def loop1(sc):
    fb = type('fb',(object,),{'__init__':initer,
                              'link':linker,
                              'CLASSIES':0})
    print '--------'
    print 'id(fb) == %d' % id(fb)
    m1 = fb()
    m1.X = 0
    m1.link()
    print 
    m2 =fb()
    m2.X = 1
    m2.link()
    print 
    m3 =fb()
    m3.X = 2
    m3.link()
    print '--------'

    # Update loop every 10 second
    sc.enter(10, 10, loop1, (sc,))


# end loop
s.enter(1, 1, loop1, (s,))
s.run()
```

displays

```
--------
id(fb) == 18976648
Y == 2001
test == 1     self.X == 1

Y == 2001
test == 2     self.X == 2

Y == 2001
test == 3     self.X == 3
--------
--------
id(fb) == 13818640
Y == 2002
test == 4     self.X == 1

Y == 2002
test == 5     self.X == 2

Y == 2002
test == 6     self.X == 3
--------
--------
id(fb) == 18970384
Y == 2003
test == 7     self.X == 1

Y == 2003
test == 8     self.X == 2

Y == 2003
test == 9     self.X == 3
--------
--------
id(fb) == 18970864
Y == 2004
test == 10     self.X == 1

Y == 2004
test == 11     self.X == 2

Y == 2004
test == 12     self.X == 3
--------
--------
id(fb) == 18971736
Y == 2005
test == 13     self.X == 1

Y == 2005
test == 14     self.X == 2

Y == 2005
test == 15     self.X == 3
--------
--------
id(fb) == 18957224
Y == 2006
test == 16     self.X == 1

Y == 2006
test == 17     self.X == 2

Y == 2006
test == 18     self.X == 3
--------
.
.
.
etc
```

I could obtain this result only by the above way.
Deleting `fb` at the end of each turn isn't sufficient, as you will see if you make the following code run. It is your code with a few more instructions, to have `Y` and the display of `id(fb)`. You'll see that ``` `` an ```id(fb)`` remains the same from one turn to the other.

```
import sched,time

test = 0  
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

Y = 2000

def loop1(sc):
    class fb:
        def link(self):
            global test,Y
            test = test + 1
            self.X = self.X + 1
            print 'Y == %d' % Y
            print 'test == %d     self.X == %d' % (test,self.X)
    print 'id(fb) == %d' % id(fb)
    print '--------'
    m1 = fb()
    m1.X = 0
    m1.link()
    print 
    m2 =fb()
    m2.X = 1
    m2.link()
    print 
    m3 =fb()
    m3.X = 0
    m3.link()
    print '--------'
    del fb

    # Update loop every 10 second
    sc.enter(10, 10, loop1, (sc,))


# end loop
s.enter(1, 1, loop1, (s,))
s.run()
```

The reason why your code doesn't work as you would like, as far I have really understand what you want, is that the portion of script who defines the class is called "definition of the class" (incredible, isn't it ?) and when the interpretr passes on this class block the first time, it **executes** it.
The execution of a "definition of class" creates an object that is a class. As soon as the class is created, the "definition" is not re-executed if the interpreter passes again on the class' code block (= class definition).
Here again , there is an ambiguous word: 'definition' can be understood as 'the text block in the script that defines a class' or as 'the process of executing the instructions that define the creation of a class and that lead to an object being a class'
The sense I used for "definition of the class" is the one used in the doc:

> Class definitions, like function definitions (def statements) must be
>   executed before they have any effect. (You could conceivably place a
>   class definition in a branch of an if statement, or inside a
>   function.)
>
> http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax

So, finally, what I want to say is that in your code, the "definition of the class fb" is executed only one time, it's then always the same class that is modeling classes , turn after turn of the loop.

Comment: @john Thank you for the upvote. I'm satisfied to have understood correctly what you needed

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a local variable which is not reset every time. The whole point of a local variable is that it's local. So, it can't be a local variable.

But it can't be a global variable either, because you want to be able to have two different scheduled `loop1` functions that don't fight over the same variable.

So, what you need to do is reorganize things so that the loop instance is itself a thing, something that can have a variable bound to it. There are two basic ways to do this.

First, there's the traditional OO solution of creating a class, and making your function an instance method, which can then access instance variables. Something like this:

```
class Looper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 0
    def loop1(self, sc):
        # same code as before, but with self.test instead of test

looper1 = Looper()
looper2 = Looper()
s.enter(1, 1, looper1.loop1, (s,))
s.enter(1, 1, looper2.loop1, (s,))
```

Alternatively, there's the traditional FP solution of creating a closure:

```
def make_loop1():
    test = 0
    def loop1(sc):
        nonlocal test
        # same code as before, unchanged
    return loop1
looper1 = make_loop1()
looper2 = make_loop1()
s.enter(1, 1, looper1, (s,))
s.enter(1, 1, looper2, (s,))
```

And then there are various hybrid solutions, where you treat the function itself as an OO object (e.g., assign `test` as an attribute of the function), or fake a closures by passing a mutable value as an argument, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions abarnert, however I don't think nonlocal is included in python 2.7..?  And I couldn't seem to get the first example to work..?

Comment: No, `nonlocal` is not included in 2.7. The simplest trick to get around that are to pass a `tests=[test]` as an extra default value to the local function and then use `tests[0]` inside the function.

Comment: As for the first one… what does "couldn't seem to get [it] to work" mean? What code did you try, and what did it do wrong? (If there's an error, please give us the whole error and traceback, not just "it got an error". If it gave the wrong results, tell us what results it gave and what you expected, not just "it got the wrong answer". And so on.)

Comment: Hi, I got the error NameError: global name 'loop1' is not defined. I used the same code you posted with mine inserted after def loop1(self, sc):...

Comment: Your code is _not_ the same. You have to actually look at the error message—it tells you exactly which line is wrong, and it's one of the lines you added—the `s.enter(10, 10, loop1, (sc,))` inside `loop1`. And the `s.enter(1, 1, loop1, (s,))` inside the `class` has the same problem. Unlike the other calls, which use `loop1` as a member of a `Looper` instance, you're trying to use `loop1` as a global. For the first one, you probably want `self.loop1`. For the second, I don't even know what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

I've done this before... make a module, or maybe just use __ init__.py if you're comfortable with that

In __ init__.py or wherever.py

```
from somepackage.some_module import my_function
my_obj = my_function()
```

In your_awesome_module.py you can use your object

```
from path.to.wherever import my_obj
# Do stuff with my_obj
```

Comment: Hi Greg, I don't quite follow what you are suggesting...?

Comment: @john I guess in hindsight, what I was suggesting was that it sounded like you wanted something with greater complexity than just a single function. I was suggesting creating some additional files/classes whatever to help out. My thought didn't have much cohesion though, and deserved to be a comment, not an answer